# Criteria for legitimate kings

Tags: malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, book-of-haggai

Why do they say that Zerubbabel is not called king but governor as in the book of Haggai simply because he was placed by the Persians while Jehoiakim and Zedekiah are considered legitimate kings being placed by Pharaoh Necho and Nebuchadnezzar respectively? Was there any formality to declare someone legitimate king and if so which ones did Jehoiakim and Zedekiah fulfill?

Comment: Who are "they" that say this?

Comment: I hear this from several places and in fact it is not even the most important, it states that Zerubbabel is not called king of Judah in the Bible, but simply governor because he was a vassal of the Persians administering a province of the Persian empire and that only kings who held sovereignty of your country was called king in the writings, there we have Jehoiachin and Zedekiah placed on the throne by foreign kings and the writings consider them legitimate kings, did they receive the anointing as usual?

Comment: Conversely, Antalya is described as מלכת despite being female and theoretically ineligible

Comment: Could you please edit in sources that state this?

Comment: I don't know why they took the trouble to edit Jehoiachin's name, he had this and other names like Jehoiakim, Jehoikim, Eliakim, which in the end doesn't change much. I just thought it was funny but ok

Comment: If you click on the icon of the clock with a counterclockwise arrow around it you'll be able to see the post history and an explanation for the edit. The reasoning being that while Jehoiakim was put on the throne by the Egyptians, Jehoiachin was not. He merely succeeded his father.

Comment: I think we are confusing the kings, there were two kings named Jehoiachin who were also called by other names like Eliakim as he was by birth, at least in some biblical versions they did so. We are dealing with the 18 king of Judah, the son of Josiah, and his successor who was his son was also called Jehoiachin, whom Nebuchadnezzar took captive and became known as Jeconiah.

Comment: I just wanted to say that in many translations Joachim is rendered as Jehoiakim as for example the Jerusalem Bible translates them like this

Comment: You are mistaken. There was only one king named Jehoiachin. His father, who was king before him, was called Jehoiakim. See here for example: https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.24.6?vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi. Eliakim was Jehoiakim's original name. Coniahu and Jeconiah are two variants of Jehoiachin's name. These are two separate individuals with different names.

Comment: In fact the two are called Jehoiakim but what Pharaoh Neco changed the name also in some versions is called Jehoikim you understand?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehoiakim

Comment: No, I don't understand. I see you aren't providing verses as evidence, nor have you edited in people who make the claim you are questioning in your question.

Comment: Actually I'm not protesting, I just found it funny since the king I mentioned also in some versions has a variant in his name that in the end doesn't change the main question.

Comment: I believe the disagreement about the name is in the Septuagint when they were translated into Latin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140400/discussion-between-harel13-and-thales).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I still I don't know who argues that Zerubavel only held gubernatorial and not kingly status simply because he was given the leadership position by the Persians as opposed to the Babylonian or the Egyptians, it is evident that Zerubavel was never referred to as king. Sheshbatzar at best was [called](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.1.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) a nasi (prince) but even this term, in the original Aramaic is [translated](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.5.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) as פחה (pekha), governor.

Why were they not considered vassal kings? The reason is simple: Babylon deprived Judah of its status as a vassal state and made it into a governor-controlled territory. We can see this was the appointment of Gedalyahu ben Achikam after the exile ([Kings 2:25:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.25.22?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi); [Yirmiyahu 40:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.40.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)). Gedalyahu is not referred to as king, nor are we ever told that he was a descendant of the House of David. He and his relatives and ancestors attained important court positions, but that's it.

Persia inherited this status quo and decided to keep things the way they were. States that remained vassals under Babylon continued on in this capacity during the Persian era, and states that became governorships under the Babylonians remained so under the Persians. For more information, see [this](https://www.academia.edu/13508529/Royal_Vassals_or_Governors_On_the_status_of_Sheshbazzar_and_Zerubbabel_in_the_Persian_Empire_Henoch_22_2000_pp_35_44) essay by Nadav Ne'eman.

Comment: But who wrote the biblical books followed international treaties or followed a mentality of heaven? For until then kings had to follow a protocol to be considered kings, such as being anointed by the high priest, etc. Or did it end after Solomon?

Comment: @Thales I don't see the contradiction. The reality is that for whatever reason, Sheshbatzar and Zerubavel were simply not kings. Tanach does not contradict that. Regarding most kings it's not said that they were anointed. They might have been, and they might not have been. In legal terms, the vassal king and the governor have different jurisdictions and different expectations from the mother state.

Comment: Later Jewish tradition holds that Zerubavel eventually decided to leave Judah and go back to Babylon, subsequently creating the lineage of the Exilarchy or Resh Galutah. We don't find kings abdicating their thrones and moving to another country. This tells us that also according to Jewish tradition he was not recognized as a king.

Comment: This question of kings is very interesting, because we have Saul, David and Solomon appointed by God himself and receiving the anointing and from Rehoboam this does not happen anymore, now the firstborn who inherits the throne regardless of the will of God and if he did not receive the anointing of the high priest and yet they are legitimate kings and expected to do “what was right in the eyes of the Lord”

Comment: @Thales bear in mind that there were also kings of Israel who were anointed and others who were not (at least not explicitly) yet all were expected to lead justly and conform to the Torah. Likewise, Cyrus was called by Isaiah a משיח, an anointed, although he was not Jewish and likely, in historic terms, never anointed by a high priest or a prophet.

Comment: Both of these tell us that the criteria of being a king according to the Torah doesn't begin or end with merely being physically anointed. One of my professors last year suggested that a king, according to Tanach, is someone who can tax a certain territory. The governor could only tax as called for by the mother state. This is one of the reasons that the Jews hated the Roman governors, because they claimed they were taxing according to what Roman law demanded, but in reality took more.

Comment: The vassal king has to meet a certain quota of taxes and/or military support but is otherwise free to rule his people as he sees fit.

Comment: But anointed doesn't always mean to be king. Cyrus' question has to do with an eschatological role that he would play or we would have to say that Persia followed the Torah and God anointed Cyrus to be king of Persia. The question of the kings of Israel has more to do with my doubt in the relationship of legitimacy on the part of God than because he fulfills certain earthly obligations, for some reason God stopped instituting who would be the next king? After what Solomon did, did God give them their lot as to who would be king?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140399/discussion-between-harel13-and-thales).